# Remove top shadow in my grouped UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am a little OCD and this is driving me insane. I have been messing around with these settings for a long time.

I have a UITableView grouped that I have a shadow on the top. When you tap the top cell, it removes. What gives?

I've been stressing over this for the past hour or so. Is there a simple solution for this? Or am I just going insane?

Thanks,
Coulton

[image]

**EDIT:**

viewDidLoad:

```
formTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
formTableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
formTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(194.0 / 255.0) green:(194.0 / 255.0) blue:(194.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
```

Here is how I display my cells. **WARNING:** It's a lot of code. There's a bunch of stuff in there you will have to sort through, so sort through it at your own risk! :)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

// What to do when you click delete.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return NO;
}

//RootViewController.m
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (section == 0) {
    return [formDataOne count];
} else {
    return [formDataTwo count];
}
}

//RootViewController.m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue;
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cellValue = [formDataOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cellValue = [formDataTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.text = @"";
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        addTitle = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 13, 280, 20)];
        addTitle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        addTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //text color
        addTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];  //font size
        addTitle.placeholder = @"Album Name";  //place holder
        addTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //background color
        addTitle.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   // no auto correction support
        addTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // type of the keyboard
        addTitle.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // type of the return key
        addTitle.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right
        addTitle.delegate = self;   // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed
        [cell.contentView addSubview:addTitle];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        // Set up loading text and show it
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 13, 280, 20)];
        myLabel.text = @"Private Album";
        myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 16.0];
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        //[myLabel sizeToFit];


        privateSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
        [privateSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:privateSwitch];
        //[privateSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];

        if ([howToDisplay isEqualToString:@"no"]) {
            [privateSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
        } else {
            [privateSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
        }



        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
    } else {
        // Set up loading text and show it
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 13, 280, 20)];
        myLabel.text = @"Comments";
        myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 16.0];
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        //[myLabel sizeToFit];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];

        commentsSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:commentsSwitch];
        [commentsSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
    }

} else {
    //cell.text = cellValue;

    UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 12, 130, 20)];
    labelOne.text = cellValue;
    labelOne.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [labelOne setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    labelOne.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    labelOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //labelOne.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"];
    labelOne.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];



    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        int countFacebook = [dataCeter.connectionFacebookArray count];
        if (countFacebook == 0) {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        } else {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
    }  else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    //}  else if (indexPath.row == 3) {

    }  else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        int countTumblr = [dataCeter.connectionTumblrArray count];
        if (countTumblr == 0) {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        } else {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
    }  else if (indexPath.row == 4) {

    }  else if (indexPath.row == 5) {

    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

}

// Set imageView with correct thumbnail
UIImage *theImage;
if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_facebook.png"];
    int countFacebook = [dataCeter.connectionFacebookArray count];
    NSLog(@"facebook? %d // %@", countFacebook, dataCeter.connectionFacebookArray);

    if (countFacebook != 0) {
        facebookSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:facebookSwitch];
        [facebookSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

} else if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Twitter"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_twitter.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

} else if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Flickr"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_flickr.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

} else if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Tumblr"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_tumblr.png"];
    int countTumblr = [dataCeter.connectionTumblrArray count];

    if (countTumblr != 0) {
        tumblrSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tumblrSwitch];
        [tumblrSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

} else if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Email"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_email.png"];
    int countEmail = [dataCeter.connectionEmailArray count];

} else if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"MMS"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_mms.png"];
    int countMMS = [dataCeter.connectionSMSArray count];

} else if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Photostream"]) {

    theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_small_photostream.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    photostreamSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:photostreamSwitch];
    [photostreamSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];

} else {

    theImage = nil;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
cell.imageView.image = theImage;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your table view's separator style to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`. It's currently being set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched`, which gives the effect of a doubled top border on the iPhone (it looks more detailed on iOS 5, and on iOS 3.2 and 4 on the iPad).

Comment: It's `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` :)... Thanks so much! My solution: `formTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;`

Answer (score 1):

You're not insane, it looks like there is an extra pixel in there.

Try taking out "Sharing" and see if it still happens.  Curious to see if the shadow is on "Sharing" or the table itself.

If that's the case, then you know your header view has a problem, not the table view.

Comment: Removed it and it's still there.

Comment: Can I see your table code that generates the cells and sets the heights?

Comment: These 2 lines are kinda confusing to me: 
formTableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
formTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(194.0 / 255.0) green:(194.0 / 255.0) blue:(194.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];  -- what happens if you comment them out?

Comment: The extra pixel on the top isn't a problem with the header. It's with the table view, and that's easily solved.